# Checking what PHP version I'm running on Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, php

I'm running Centos 5 and I need to know what version of PHP I'm running, is there a command for this which I can run?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Try running the following at the command line.

To just get the version information:

```
php -v
```

Or to get a lot of info:

```
php -i
```

It should give you all information you need about the php install.

Comment: +1 php -v was a lot faster

Comment: Thx, this worked :-) php -i | grep 'PHP Version' gave me the answer

Comment: Just be cautious that the CLI version of PHP (checked from command line) can be different from the one served by your webserver (shown by phpinfo())

Comment: And php-cli maybe not installed in the system

Answer (score 19):

You can make an `index.php` file with

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

Comment: this has the advantage of working on servers you don't have ssh access to, though personally I've always preferred <?php ?>, just for the futureproofing :P

Comment: Ah, right, I have a habit of using ASP tags.

Comment: On *any* PHP website one can often see the version in the `X-Powered-By` header in each PHP generated HTTP response. When you don't have SSH access, then sometimes http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/ can be used. (Though with much care, like one needs to check if a folder is writable before running a `tar` command.)

Comment: this should be the correct answer

Answer (score 12):

An answer was accepted, but another option on RPM systems (RHEL, Centos, Fedora, etc.) is to use the following:

```
rpm -q php
```

And while I'm at it, the general method for using RPM to find info on a package for any rpm-installed program or file is similar to this (for awk):

1. Find the full path to the file if not known, such as for an executable in $PATH:

   > **type -path** *awk*
2. Find the name, including version, of the package containing the file:

   > **rpm -qf** */usr/bin/awk*
3. If desired, query for info from that package:

   > **rpm -qi** *gawk*

It's a bit trickier for packages installed and used by Apache since they may not be on $PATH, but you can start with something like:

> **rpm -qa** | egrep -i 'php|awk'

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
more /etc/php.ini
```

This will show you:

1. Apache Version
2. PHP Versions
3. PHP Functions
4. Various options regarding PHP