# Checking what PHP version I'm running on Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, php, version

I'm running Debian 6 and I need to know what version of PHP I'm running, is there a command for this which I can run?

I tried "php -i" and "php -v" from a [previous question..](https://superuser.com/questions/28633/checking-what-php-version-im-running-on-linux)

```
root@azaz07:/srv/www/site.com/public_html# php -i
bash: php: command not found
root@azaz07:/srv/www/site.com/public_html# php -v
bash: php: command not found
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I tried "php -v"

A command like this will only work if you have the CLI version of PHP installed.  If you have only the Apache module version of PHP this will not work.

You can install the CLI version with this command:

```
apt-get install php5-cli
```

That should make the info and version commands work.

If PHP was installed via your package manager then a command like this might give useful results.

```
# dpkg -l | grep php
ii  libapache2-mod-php5                                    5.3.3-7+squeeze17            server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  libphp-phpmailer                                       5.1-1                        full featured email transfer class for PHP
ii  libzend-framework-php                                  1.11.9-0ubuntu1              a simple, straightforward, open-source software framework for PHP 5
ii  libzend-framework-zendx-php                            1.11.9-0ubuntu1              a simple, straightforward, open-source software framework for PHP 5
ii  php-apc                                                3.1.3p1-2                    APC (Alternative PHP Cache) module for PHP 5
ii  php-html-common                                        1.2.5-1                      A base class for other HTML classes
hi  php-html-template-it                                   1.3.0-1                      Integrated Templates
...
```

If PHP wasn't installed with your package manager and instead manually installed, then you might have to simply create a PHP script that looks like this `<?php phpinfo();` and then access that script through your web browser.

Comment: In case of `<?php phpinfo();` be sure to restrict access to the file for anyone, but you.

Comment: It does appeared to be installed from that, thanks. How would I get commands to work from the command line?  There seems to be so many commands I cannot use that crop up in various tutorials.. like "php --ini" Do I need to install a seperate package to make the command line stuff work?

Comment: @some1, I am not a Debian user, but try to install [php-cli package](http://packages.debian.org/sid/php5-cli)

Comment: It was php5-cli, thanks, a lot of the commands that weren't working do now.